# Scandal's beginnings

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

[image]

**Across**
6. A sign that it's time to stop payment: Serious warning signal (9,4)
8. Nonconformist man is in good shape (6)
9. Sorriest broken component (8)
10. Child keeping King softly in grip (5,3)
12. Dessert and wine brought back to a king and a queen? (6)
14. DJ's Maui resort shows faith (7)
16. Child has day in France, which is a short stay (7)
18. Maybe Prince Charlie, President Kennedy and Prince Albert disregard everything except conclusions? (6)
19. Convicts rot in a jail, holding back custodians (8)
21. Tamper with ghetto quite regularly without holding back (5,3)
23. Desert manoeuvre: Consuming Worms? Native's agreement (6)
25. News sources: Princess rushed to embrace mature Englishman – Scandal's beginnings? (5,8)

**Down**
1. Bridges in Paris I strongly fancied, at first (4)
2. Adjacent placements of Whedon, holding up tax, surprisingly keeping it by charge (14)
3. Extremely rowdy conduct during *Insider Exclusive* dress rehearsals (3,4)
4. Rifle she'd outlined, framed, created basic structure for (7,3)
5. African native's extremely intoxicating body odour (4)
6. Stylish, slightly overconfident Latino (5)
7. Carelessly dip spa lotion, resulting in unsatisfied feeling (14)
11. Bible's first part is missing Uriah's 7 down (5,5)
13. Musical sensibility seen on occasion in Bel Air (3)
15. Russian parliament decapitated woman (3)
17. One old-timey Dane owns silver tube (7)
20. Vera's swinging dance parties (5)
22. Indonesia's top representatives are evil beings (4)
24. Associate recreational running with the loss of a few grams (4)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Today, Jafe just enjoyed J's!

**Completed Grid**

> [image]

**ACROSS**

> 6. CHEQUERED FLAG = CHEQUE + RED FLAG
>  8. MISFIT = M (man) + IS + FIT
>  9. RESISTOR = SORRIEST*
>  10. BOBBY PIN = BOY (child) + BB (BB King) + P (softly) + IN
>  12. PIECES = PIE + SEC<
>  14. JUDAISM = DJ'S MAUI*
>  16. SOJOURN = SON + JOUR
>  18. JACKET = JACK (President Kennedy) + _E _T (Prince Albert)
>  19. JANITORS = convictS ROT IN Jail<
>  21. RIGHT OUT = RIG + gHeTtO qUiTe
>  23. MOJAVE = MOVE + JA (Worms Native's agreement)
>  25. PRESS AGENCIES = PRINCESS* + AGE + E_ S_

**DOWN**

> 1. JEFF = JE (in Paris I) + F (strongly, forte) + F_ (fancied at first)
>  2. JUXTAPOSITIONS = JOSS + UP TAX* + IT + ION
>  3. DRY RUNS = RowdY + RUN (conduct) + DresS (insider exclusive dress)
>  4. FLESHED OUT = riFLE SHE'D OUTlined
>  5. IGBO = I_G + BO (body odor)
>  6. CHICO = CHIC + O_
>  7. DISAPPOINTMENT = DIP SPA* + OINTMENT
>  11. BLACK SHEEP = B_ + LACKS + HEEP (Uriah Heep)
>  13. EAR = bEl AiR
>  15. UMA = (-d)UMA
>  17. AJUTAGE = A + JUTE + AG
>  20. RAVES = VERA'S*
>  22. IMPS = I_ + MPS (representatives, members of parliament)
>  24. JOIN = JO(-gg)IN(-g) (loss of a few grams...very clever!)

Comment: Dang! I misspelled 23 across with an H instead of a J ;_;

Comment: Enjoy them I did, and I actually wanted more! The original idea was rot13(gb unir rirel jbeq pbagnva W rkprcg n unaqshy bs nafjref, naq gur nafjref zvffvat gur W jbhyq nyy or jbeqf fubjvat gung gurl qba'g "orybat" fhpu nf zvfsvg, oynpx furrc, qvfnccbvagzrag rgp.) But I couldn't get it to work like I wanted, so we have a vanilla crossword instead :) Nice work on the solve!

Comment: @jafe That would have been tough to make happen, but would have been epic. The result as is was still a nice challenging solve...took me a while to really break in, but went well once I did. 1-Down took me a long time to get, but I really enjoyed it when I did. And it is pretty fitting with the theme that I got the checkmark :-)